# Grub not showing debian partition

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, windows, grub

I have a hard drive sda with 3 OSs:

- Windows 10
- Debian
- Ubuntu

After installing Ubuntu, Debian partition is not showing anymore.
I tried to update the grub from Ubuntu:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This is the output of this command [image]

Debian is correctly detected in the sda6. However it is not displayed in the grub after restarting:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. How can I restore the Debian entry in the grub?
2. Is it possible to hide the entry sda1 and sda2?

**EDIT 1**:
When I installed Debian I created a separated boot partition. This is the content under this partition:

- Boot
- bootmgr
- BOOTNXT
- BOOTSECT.BAK
- '$RECYCLE.BIN'
- 'System Volume Information'

**EDIT 2**:
After editing "/etc/grub.d/40_custom" with the custom entry:

```
menuentry 'Debian on /dev/sda6' {
    set root='hd0,gpt6'
    search --fs-uuid --set=root uuid_debian_partition_here
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-9-amd64 root=UUID=uuid_here ro 
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-9-amd64        
}
```

I see the debian entry in the grub. However after hitting ENTER the following screen is displayed:
[image]

**EDIT 3**:
This is the content of the mounted partition:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   4096 Jul 20 15:21  .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   4096 Jul 20 15:03  ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8192 Jul 17 01:28  Boot
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 410802 Jul 17 00:59  bootmgr
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      1 Mär 19 05:44  BOOTNXT
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 Jul 20 15:21  boot-repair
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8192 Jul 17 06:00  BOOTSECT.BAK
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 Jul 19 07:39 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 Jul 19 05:57 'System Volume Information'
```

Comment: (1) Any chance the Debian entry was moved to the "Advanced options"? Check and report if the entry is missing in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.
(2) You can hide the windows partitions by setting `GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST="UUID_SDA1@/dev/sda1 UUID_SDA2@/dev/sda2"` in `/etc/default/grub` (replace with the real UUIDs and separate both entries with a space), see https://askubuntu.com/a/514205

Comment: @Freddy There is no grub.cfg file under "/boot/grub" and the entry is not moved to "Advanced options"